# Setting Excel file permission when creating file through PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

In my site, I am generating reports (custom code) in an excel format. What happens is that it creates the Excel file at a location and then user is supposed to download from there through a link.

The problem is that this file is being created with permission of 600 which means that the user is unable to download it. Is there any way it can have 644 (or higher) permission?

The code is below ...

### Code:-

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);

$tosave = str_replace("customfunctions.php","/files/customfunctions.php", __FILE__);

$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', $tosave));
```

Comment: PHPExcel does nothing to set file permissions: it's up to your code to ensure that the folder you're writing to has all appropriate privileges to ensure that the saved file has the appropriate permissions

Comment: But the folder has 644 permission but still this file being saved is with 600. So does it mean that there is nothing we can do in the code? It has to be done on the server?

Comment: I'm saying that PHPExcel simply saves the file, and makes no effort to manage the file permissions in any way

Comment: I am a bit unclear here. Since this is where I am creating the file in the code, there must be some way through which I can set permissions.

Answer (score 0):

PHPExcel won't be changing the permissions, it'll just create the file and save it. If you need to set the permissions to anything other than the default you can use [chmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) to do so.

e.g.: `chmod("/somedir/somefile.xls", 0644);`